# How to edit the root window in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

I want to change the background window but like on most windows applications there is that border around your program that is default. But I am wondering how would I go about changing the root window like how steam has theirs? Like a box?

I have looked online but I can not find anything does anyone know anything about this that can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True)
```

Note that this completely disables the frame, making the window unmovable. You have to implement this at your own then.